# Can I close the current browser window and give the focus back to the application that had it before the tab opened?

Tags: macos, oauth, command-line-interface

I'm developing a shell based application. At some point I need to get an oauth token. To do so I start a local server, and open a tab in a browser that'll redirect to the local url once the token is obtained. This seems quite standard, for instance here's [Okta's story](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/16/oauth-2-command-line#the-trick-to-oauth-20-on-the-command-line).

I would like the user to automatically come back to the shell once the token is obtained and the tab is closed. Can I do so?

1. Start a local server from my shell based program, listening on localhost:3001:

```
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>window.close();</script></body></html>');
  server?.close();
  token = req.query.token;
});
server = app.listen(3001);
```

2. Open a webpage that'll communicate the token back to my local server:

```
open http://mywebsite.com/auth/redirect_url=localhost:3001
```

3. In the local server, respond to any request with `window.close();` (see above)

This works fine in term of getting the token in the shell from the browser. However once the above is done, **the user is faced with their default browser** on the last tab that was opened before the one launched from the shell, instead of the shell.

Can I do the same and yield the focus back to the shell when closing the tab?

Answer (score 0):

You probably would use in-context launch technique to start(navigate to) the oauth login session. After login completed, you can navigate back to your session.

Comment: and how do you do that?